# Is there a good plain TeX tutorial that explains about doing automation and making layout?

Tags: documentation, plain-tex, book-design, tutorials

I am interested in learning plain TeX especially in

1. automation: looping, conditional branching, jumping, iterating, etc.
2. layout: creating custom smart tables and boxes that can span cross pages.

What is the most often used commands for doing those above? At least I have a rough direction to the target.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Reading Knuth's book needs much time. I want to be more practical and instant first. Later after grasping the rough and basic understanding, I will read the Knuth's book.

Comment: I'm afraid that for tables in particular there are no short-cuts. The `\halign` primitive is something you need to be very careful with, hence the complexity of many of the table packages around.

Comment: `Smile, breathe and go slowly.` - Thich Nhat Hanh. Automation in TeX is easy there is one construct and that is `recursion` everything is build around this, including the `loop`. Branching is a few primitives `\if`, `ifnum` etc. As Joseph mentioned the table building mechanism is complicated and has been `overwritten` by LaTeX, so if you play with TeX tables you need to stick to TeX mostly. There are some good suggestions by the posters below. Try reading the `TeXbook` or at least skimping through it first.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: `\halign` works just fine in LaTeX, so I don't know what you mean by "overwritten".

Comment: @morbusg: not only does latex not overwrite `\halign`, it also goes so far as to use it ... which isn't terribly surprising, if you think about it...  (not that it's relevant here, since the op wants to know about plain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know only of two:

http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/

http://mirror.ctan.org/info/impatient/

You'll find free pdf versions of the books in the directories. If you will be a member of DANTE (Germans TeX user group http://www.dante.de) you'll get a free copy of the book TeX by Topic`. At least for mebers in 2014.

Comment: I will try to read chapter 9 of **TeX for the Impatient**. I think it is what I need. Thanks very much for the links.

Comment: I'd recommend making clear what those links are to.

Comment: @Seamus, just click *.pdf from the list shown.

Comment: @xport The point is to make clear what those links are _for_. It's all very well giving a link, but it's better to give a link and an explanation of what those links are...

Comment: @Seamus, it is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you will have here is that a lot of the basic work on plain TeX programming was reported in [*TUGBoat*](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/), which therefore means things are spread out. At the same time, a lot of the basics are leant from existing code, rather than from books. This applies in particular to loops, where most people use ideas from *The TeXbook*, *etc*., and adapt them. For tables, you'll be best looking at the various LaTeX packages and the ConTeXt TaBlE implementation for ideas. This reflects the fact that once something is implemented in TeX, the usual way to reuse the idea is to copy the code. It's not the same a a compiled language where you need to know about the implementation approach without the option of simply copying all of the code.

Comment: yes, TUGboat is a good source, especially the "ask Nelly" section

Comment: Many things are spread out there. Thanks for the link, @Joseph. I will revisit the link after reading the book **TeX for the Impatient** (chapter 9).

Comment: and it is also a good idea to be a member of TUG ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert, someday I will register.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to *TeX for the Impatient*, I also like looking at Don Knuth's TeX code, most of which is available on his homepage: [Preprints of Recent Papers](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/preprints.html).

The CTAN [plain contrib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/samples/) may also be useful, as well as [Eplain: Expanded Plain TeX](http://www.tug.org/docs/html/eplain/).

Comment: [CTAN plain/contrib -- contributed code to work with Plain TeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/) contains a lot of good stuff, and quite a lot of dross; sadly, painfully much of it is completely undocumented :-(