# Grouping the list of listings by chapter

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, listings

I am using the `listings` package. I want to print out a list of listings, which I can do. The thing is that in the other listings the typesetter "groups" figures/tables by chapter. Is it possible to achieve a similar behaviour with the list of listings?

Here is an example

[image: Example of how I want it]

Here is how it is now

[image: How it is]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write into the preamble:

```
\let\Chapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}\Chapter}
```

Comment: This solution seems better as it works automatically for every chapter. I need to learn how to make those kinds of macros, where should I start?

Comment: Difficult to say, because there are tons of manuals ... For TeX related stuff: `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/` and for LaTeX see `http://mirror.ctan.org/info/`

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your preamble (adjusted for the `book` and `report` class):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \chaptermark{#1}%
}{
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lol}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

EDIT: The "chapter gap" mechanism of the `KOMA-Script` classes works for any "listofsomething".

Comment: Your _hack_ worked. Unfortunately the `listings` package only provides a `\lstlistoflistings` which does not match the `\listofsomething` rule. Is there a better package for listings?

Comment: @Tiago: I shouldn't have use code tags for "listofsomething". The KOMA-Script classes control the layout of `\lstlistoflistings`.